# Dockerfile: Repository not found when adding a name to the stage

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to create a Docker image but am running into a problem I don't quite understand (I am not very experienced in using Docker).

The problem is the following line in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM sgrio/java-oracle:jdk_8 AS builder
```

Here is what happens:

```
me@here:~$ sudo docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM sgrio/java-oracle:jdk_8 AS builder
Pulling repository sgrio/java-oracle
INFO[0004] Repository not found
```

If i remove the "AS builder" from the line, the repository gets pulled without problems. However, I need to name the stage for referencing later in the Dockerfile, so removing it is (I assume) not an option.

What am I missing here? All my searches on the net says that this should work.

I am using Docker v1.6.2 on ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Comment: The docker version is very old. Try updating it.

Comment: Thanks. Updating docker fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually updated docker to version 17.06 and now it works as expected. Looks like the version that comes with Ubuntu 14.04 is not usable anymore.